# Java models, get rid of multiple maps

Tags: java, generics, model

please consider following structure

***BaseModel.java*** -> abstract base class

***Company.java***, ***Person.java*** -> some models, that inherit from ***BaseModel.java***

***Context.java*** -> context class that stores all models, that might look like this:

```
public class Context
{
    private Map<String, Company> companyModels = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, Person> personModels = new HashMap<>();

    public void addCompany(Company company)
    {
        companyModels.put(company.getCompanyName(), company);
    }

    public Company getCompany(String companyName)
    {
        return companyModels.get(companyName);
    }

    public void addPerson(Person person)
    {
        personModels.put(person.getPersonFullName(), person);
    }

    public Person getPerson(String personFullName)
    {
        return personModels.get(personFullName);
    }
}
```

Sometimes, when for example creating person, I need to get reference to the company, that is why I have maps both for Company and Person.

Now it seems okay, but the problem is, there will be many different models, so for each model there will need to be map, and two methods, one that adds it to map, and another that retrieves.

How to simplify it?

I was thinking about enum:

```
public enum ModelType
{
    Company,
    Person
}
```

and inside my ***Context.java***

```
private Map<ModelType, Map<String, BaseModel>> models = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


/**
 * Retrieve some company details
 */
private void test()
{
    String companyName = ((Company) models.get(ModelType.COMPANY).get("Some company name")).getCompanyName();
}
```

But I would prefer to avoid casting if possible, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I would advise against the `Enum` approach since you store different types in a unified collection, which sound counter intuitive. --- "*Now it seems okay, but the problem is, there will be many different models*" - Why? Or asked in another way: can you maybe regroup certain parts to extract them in their own context? Is there a use case where you need all maps at once? Is creating separate contexts per use case that hold only references to the maps they need for this use case (separation fo concerns)?

Comment: For example person will belong to company, when creating person, I will only know the name of the company (and at this stage company will be already created and present in the context with all models) now from Person model I will be easily able to get reference to the Company model. 

There might be cases when I will be creating only Company, but no People, or Company and People, thank you for answer.

Comment: Have you considered making a generic context typed to `? extends BaseModel` which you can re-use for each new model? You could also create an interface for models which has an unique `getIentifier()` so the context doesn't have to know which key is used for model-retrieval. I think this question is too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: @Matthewek Habe you considered a DDD approach? Does a `Person` exist on its own or is it always bound to a `Company`? If so: Have you considered making `Company` an aggregation-root and `Person` an entity of this root?

Comment: No I have not (heave not heard about it, will check it now) yes Person can exist on its own as well, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some extent, I agree with @Turing85 that you would be better off keeping your maps separated, however, if you absolutely need to, you can use classes instead of an additional enum type:

```
public class Context {
    private final Map<Class<?>,Map<String,Object>> classMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(String name, Object obj) {
        Map<String,Object> map = classMap.get(obj.getClass());
        if (map == null) {
            map = new HashMap<>();
            classMap.put(obj.getClass(), map);
        }
        map.put(name, obj);
    }

    public <T> T get(String name, Class<T> clazz) {
        Map<String,Object> map = classMap.get(clazz);
        if (map == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return clazz.cast(map.get(name));
    }
}
```